# Sorting RegExes for comparing in php

Tags: php, regex

I have a really huge numberrange to check against lots of regular expressions.
In order to improve the number of comparisons, I want to remove those regexp, that are "smaller" than the starting number range.

I could not find any information wether a simple "<" smaller would work on recognizing if I compare it like strings.

ie:

```
if($regexp > $number)
   array_push($sorted_regex, $regexp);
```

> Regexp would include following special characters: . [abc] [a-b] * +

Numbers against to check are always given in a range as starting number and ending number. 
So what I wanna do is just check those, that could possibly match any number in that range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to compare pattern strings and expect you compared potential pattern results. You may need to sit down and optimize order of your patterns manually, moving all these which match most often to the top of your list.

Comment: maybe I made it not clear enough. Maybe one more example: lots of regexp against to test start with another prefix, than the given range starts. those regexp would definetely not match, so for not comparing against them, I would not push them into the array which would be used to match against the input number range. Do you understand what I mean? :/